# How to manage sumproduct with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following code: I'm trying to use sumproduct function with vba but it doesn't work. I've tried with evaluate function but I got the same bad result.

```
Dim row As Long
Dim rows As Range
Dim us As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngl As Range
Dim rngo As Range
Dim rngp As Range

With Sheets("Report")
    LastRow = .Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
End With

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT").Range("g3:g" & LastRow) 
Set rngl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT").Range("F3:f" & LastRow)  

Set rngo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT").Range("c3:c" & LastRow)  

For us = 3 To 33
    Range("e" & us).Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((sheets(luglio).Range(c & us))<rng)*(sheets(luglio).Range(c & us)=rngl)")
Next us
```

Comment: worksheetfunction.sumproduct

Comment: No, `Worksheetfunction.Sumproduct` does not digest boolean expressions like that (works only with the real formula on the real worksheet).

Comment: To use Evaluate you have to pass a formula string as you would use it on a worksheet-i.e. range addresses not Worksheet/Range objects.

Comment: It'll be way faster (coding wise as well as execution speed wise) to implement the SUMPRODUCT function directly in your UDF than jump through hoops to invoke the WorksheetFunction.

Answer (score 1):

As Rory mentions in the comments, this isn't working because VBA is passing the entire string inside the quotations marks to Excel. You need to concatenate the strings to get the desired output as you would see in the Excel formula.

Try replacing the line:

```
 Range("e" & us).Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((sheets(luglio).Range(c & us))<rng)*(sheets(luglio).Range(c & us)=rngl)")
```

With:

```
 Range("e" & us).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT((luglio!C" & us & "<REPORT!G3:G" & LastRow & ")*(luglio!C" & us & "=REPORT!F3:F" & LastRow & "))"
```